# IdentityServer URL throws HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: identity-server

I have vanilla 9.1 instance and I can login successfully. I browsed the Identity server URL and receiving HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure. Any idea why it is throwing 502.5 error?

[image]
Log file shows these exceptions.

```
Exception: System.IO.IOException
Message: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'.
Source: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.<GetDocumentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.<GetAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__24.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 502 (Bad Gateway).
Source: System.Net.Http
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.<GetDocumentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my Okta integration. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. Mine still throws 502.5 Process Failure. If you find a solution, please let me know.

Comment: I had the same error as you showed on your first screenshot. My problem was resolved when I updated the Sitecore license on the SI server, since mine had expired.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unresolved/abandoned by OP.

Comment: I know the question is closed, but I thought it worth to add I had the same issue, but in my case I was missing the .NET Core 2.1.3 Runtime or later. See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1